# Set position of JTextField, JLabel and JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, layout-manager

When i run the program, the `label` `textfield` and `button` and so on are arranged randomly (label and button are in same line).

How do I explicitly set the layout?

Answer (score 3):

which technology do you use? Java Swing? Then I can recommend you the following manual:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#set

You should work with so called "Layout Managers", which support you in arranging different labels, fields and so on.

greets

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `setBounds(x,y,length,heigth)` and `setLayout(null)`. So you can set its coordinates.